# How to program git to do things before commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I have been looking at git hooks but haven't been able to figure this out: When the user commits a file to my git repository, I want to automatically update another file in the repo and add those changes to that same commit, and also run some commands based on what is in the commit message. Is there a way to do this? The `pre-commit` git hook seems to run before the commit message is produced.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this, using the `prepare-commit-msg` hook ... but don't.  It's difficult and error-prone, and it will be somewhat astonishing to someone familiar with Git, but not familiar with your particular project.  (That someone might be you, yourself, a few years later: I know this because it's happened to me. :-) Not specifically with Git, but basically the same problem: I came up with a short term hack, and left it in place, and much later I was shocked when something misbehaved, only to trace it to my own short-term hack.)

Instead, write a little script that does everything you want done, including running `git commit`, and leave the future maintainer (possibly yourself) instructions on how to run the little script.  You can then include the script in the Git repository for the project, so that everyone has it.

Comment: Create a script that runs `git commit`... That's an interesting idea. I would like to be able to use this, however, with Git GUI apps like SourceTree so I don't know if this is an option. Is there any reason why creating a `prepare-commit-msg` script is a bad idea, besides the (probably smart notion) that it might be an issue if I forgett how it works in the future?

Comment: By the time the prepare-commit-msg script runs, at least some versions of Git have already decided what files are going into the commit, so to modify the set of files, you must modify the index, run a *new* commit (disabling recursion on your script) and then make the outer commit fail. I made this work once, but it was confusing to use even when I expected it, and behaved badly with `git commit --amend`. Since then, Git was modified to re-check the index after early hooks run, which made it less confusing, but still kind of tricky. It also generally plays badly with `git add -p`.